# Parsing a JSON POST request to a object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am quite new to rails. I have this code in my controller:

```
@schedules = Schedules.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = ?", params[:id]])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # list.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @schedules.to_json }
end
```

This works super, but how do I get the other way? How do I parse the received JSON to a Schedules object?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Schedule.new.from_json(json)
```